# AADSTS500112: The reply address 'http://testurl' does not match the reply address 'https://testurl' when requesting Authorization code

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

i'm trying to integrate java application with azure ad .

i have registered an app in azure and added redirect url's , after successful login , it was redirected to my java application where i am fetching authorization code using msal library.

Getting the below exception

com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS500112: The reply address

'http://testUrl' does not match the reply address 'https://testUrl

the only difference i see in the above url's is http and https, even though i mentioned https in both redirect url in the app registrations as well as redirect_uri in the microsoft login url.

btw, it was working with my local environment, not working when i hosted it on the server .

Comment: mkay, why dont you add the `http` url?

Comment: azure app registration by default only allowing https url as redirect url , so i cannot make it http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research,  the redirect URL for web apps and services must begin with the scheme `https`. If you want to use the scheme `http`, you just can use `http:\\localhost`. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#restrictions-on-redirect-urls

Answer (score 7):

We had the same issue after it was deployed in production environment. The reason the https became http is since I was in a load-balanced environment, the outside URL differed from the inside URL (The load balancers off-loaded the SSL processing). When the http request from azure reached our web filter, the httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString() get the http instead of https. What we did is, ask devops team to add a header in httprequest with the original url sent to load balancer, and in our code, we extract the http header instead of the http request itself.

Specifically, change

```java
String currentUri = httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
```

to

```java
String currentUri = httpRequest.req.getHeader(HEADER_PROXY_URL);
```

The `HEADER_PROXY_URL` is the header name that devops inject the original url.

Answer (score 0):

wty1127's mention of the load-balancer was the same problem I was experiencing, but wty1127 is using Java while I'm using .NET Core. Here are the changes I made in Program.cs:

Before:

```
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

After:

```
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
{
    var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
    options.RedirectUri = section.GetValue<string>("RedirectUri") + section.GetValue<string>("CallbackPath");
})
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

This sets Microsoft Graph's redirect URI to the location it is actually deployed rather than the incorrect location that it auto-detected. The redirect URI is obtained from my appsettings.json, which has these contents:

```
{
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "my.domain.example.com",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "ClientCertificates": [],
    "TenantId": "example-guid-here",
    "ClientId": "example-guid-here",
    "ClientSecret": "example-secret-here",
    "RedirectUri": "https://url-of-my-deployed-website.example.com",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  }
}
```

So the code is just setting `options.RedirectUri = "https://url-of-my-deployed-website.example.com/signin-oidc"`. This solved the problem for me.